# Iframe in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have existing code in C# class to create iframe written old .net framework. I have to implement the same in asp.net core.
**Existing C# code in .Net framework ( *.aspx.cs)**

```
{
   HtmlGenericControl framecntymap = new HtmlGenericControl("iFrame");
            framecntymap.Attributes.Add("width", "310px");
            framecntymap.Attributes.Add("height", "310px");
            framecntymap.Attributes.Add("frameborder", "0");
            framecntymap.Attributes.Add("src", "displayTest.html");
            PanelCountyMap.Controls.Add(framecntymap);


   
}
```

**The below code is not working in asp.net core  (*.chtml) class**

```
   <iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="400px" height="400px" runat="server" src="~/GIS/displayTest.html"></iframe>
```

The src will be dynamic. I am going to update src in jquery.

How can implement similar functionality in asp.net core

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for a new project?

Comment: `runat="server"` isn't a thing anymore. Just change `<iframe src="whatever">` to `<iframe src=@( urlStringYouWantToUse )>`.

Comment: Yes. I  should have removed that. I had copied. But still not working.   The iframe will be loaded based on a value from dropdownlist.

Comment: was to able to view it. by allowing static files. But still need to know what is alternative of Iframe.

Comment: Iframes are part of HTML, that’s not the problem. Use your browser’s Developer Tools to find out why the iframe isn’t loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you can use `@Html.Raw(xx)` to generate string/object to html format.

Here is a whole working demo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ViewData["Iframe"] = @"<iframe name='myIframe' id='myIframe' width='200' height='200' src='/Home/Privacy'></iframe>";
        return View();           
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["Iframe"])
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
<h1>Privacy</h1>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Billing_Renew.ExecuteAsync() in Renew.cshtml, line 15

any idea why it is NULL and in code behind i fill with proper data as expplained?